# Make Bibliography in order of appearance of citation using {unsrt}

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sorting

I'm a total newbie at LaTeX, and I'm trying to figure out how to sort citations within a paper I'm writing for a conference based on their appearance in the document itself. The conference has a specific style they want for the paper/bibliography, so I tried using this code for my paper. When I compiled the first time, this went fine and everything was ordered properly, but then I went in to edit a citation, and recompiled in Bibtex and then LaTeX, and it went back to being alphabetically. Am I doing something wrong? What's the best way to make the bibliography sort by appearance of citation?

Thanks so much!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{ICPhS2015}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{this is the title of my paper}
\author{XXX}
\organization{XXX}
\email{XXX}
\begin{document}    

\begin{document}

Words \cite{gu_smoothing_2002} words \cite{_matlab_2012} words \cite{gu2007gss} words \cite {r_developmentcoreteam_r:_2007} words 

\bibliographystyle{ICPhS2015}{unsrt}
\bibliography{ICPhS2015}
\end{document}
```

And here's an example of the bibliography, which I want to sort by citation appearance, not by alphabetical order...

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{r_developmentcoreteam_r:_2007}
{DevelopmentCoreTeam}, R. 2007.
\newblock {\em R: A language and environment for statistical computing}.
\newblock R Foundation for Statistical Computing.

\bibitem{gu_smoothing_2002}
Gu, C. 2002.
\newblock {\em Smoothing Spline {ANOVA} Models}.
\newblock Springer Series in Statistics. Springer New York.

\bibitem{gu2007gss}
Gu, C. 2007.
\newblock gss: General smoothing splines.
\newblock http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gss/gss.pdf.

\bibitem{_matlab_2012}
MATLAB,  2012.
\newblock {\em Version 7.14.0.039 (R2012a)}.
\newblock The {MathWorks} Inc.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Your MWE is incomplete : where is your preamble with `\documentclass{article}...`?

Comment: Sorry - forgot about all of the top part and examples and such - like I said, I'm a total newbie with this awesome program >.<

Comment: The statement `\bibliographystyle{ICPhS2015}{unsrt}` doesn't look right: the macro takes only one argument, not two. What happens if you type `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` instead?

Comment: The conference style sorts by alphebatical order.  If you are submitting to them, you need to follow their style.

Comment: the same with me it is conflicted the order if you remove it, it will be fine until now I have not any choice

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the bibliography style you used in your MWE.  Do you have a link to the style so that we can use it?

So I changed your MWE to show you how you can get the wanted result. The trick is to use the bibliography style `unsrt`. Then you get the bibliography list in the order of the cite calls. Package `filecontents` is used to have the bib file and the tex code in one MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{companion,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year       = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@misc{hfs,
  Date-Added    = {2012-10-18 15:39:01 +0100},
  Date-Modified = {2012-10-18 15:44:41 +0100},
  Howpublished  = {\url{http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#technotes/tn/tn1150.html}},
  Institution   = {Apple Computer, Inc.},
  Month         = {March},
  Number        = {Technical Note TN1150},
  Title         = {HFS Plus Volume Format},
  Year          = {2004},
  key           = {Apple2},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{article}
%\usepackage{ICPhS2015}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{this is the title of my paper}
\author{test}

\begin{document}
Words \cite{hfs} words \cite{adams} words \cite{companion} words 

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

See the order of entries in the bib file and the order of calls in the MWE.

I get the following pdf file:

[image: Resulting pdf file]

Can you adapt this to your needs?

Comment: I tried to do that, the problem I had was that I couldn't use more than one style (that I know of, at least), and the icphs style (it's for a conference) is needed. Is there a way to do `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}{icphs}` or something like that?

Comment: The style can be downloaded from the [conference site](http://www.icphs2015.info/Call.aspx) in the LaTeX template.

Comment: Writing a paper for a conference usualy forces you to use the given style or classes. If you change things, for example using a modified bst file, your article will not be printed as you wish ...